# MAXSIZE=unlimited for creation of database but microsoft sql server express 2005 has only 4gb database limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i find it contradicting since microsoft sql server 2005 express has only 4gb database limit for data , so why specify MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED for creation of its database since unlimited means it will fill up the entire disk

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what question you're asking here - can you rephrase it?

Comment: what i mean is microsoft sql server express 2005 only has 4 gb size limit but why do some developers put MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED in the CREATE TABLE clause in creation of the database .Since you specify MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED then it will continue to grow until it occupies all the disk space .But the question is should it be MAXSIZE=4GB instead of MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to use the maxsize option, it will default to unlimited if you miss it out from your CREATE DATABASE statement. From what you suggest you don't seem to have a need to use the option, so you can just leave it off. There is no "right" answer in this case, feel free to use it if you want to - there will be no difference where you are using SQL Server 2005 Express, you will be contsrained to 4gb anyway.

Bear in mind that your database may not always be running on the same instance, you may wish to switch to a newer version of SQL Server or a different edition. This may remove the 4gb limitation that you currently have, which would mean if you have set the maxsize option at 4gb in your creation script you would need to change it accordingly. Growth and size options should be considered depending on the expected data that you are likely to encounter, and can potentially have a large impact on performance. [Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/) is an article that explains more about growth and sizing options in depth.